# How to handle inheritnace with Prisma?

Tags: database, inheritance, prisma

is there a way to manage inheritance in prisma ?
I have a table baseUser which contains some basic columns like name, email, password,... I also have a second table which represents a customer and I want it to contain all baseUser columns without duplication. I've tried to set a one-to-one relation but I wondered if there is any other solution like inheritance for instance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is not currently supported in Prisma.

There is an existing issue which describes progress and ideas on how `schema.prisma` file can support implementing interfaces where multiple models could implement the same interface.

[Inheritance GitHub Issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2506)